# Pass variable to strongly typed form from different view

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a little trouble passing url variables to a form on a separate view. Basically I have a **'HomeController'** which has a **'Contact'** action and view, and a **'SalesController'** which has an action and a view called **'View'**.

On the view called '**View'** (confusing I know), I have an action link like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home", new { pid = Model.Property[0].Pid, type = "Viewing"})" class="detailsBtn">
```

As you can see, this is passing two variables of **'pid'** and **'type'** to the **'Contact'** action of the **'HomeController'**. The contact returns a strongly typed view with the following model being used.

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}}
```

Here's the Contact view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="formField">
                <span class="label">Full Name *</span><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.FullName, new { @class = "txtContact" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.FullName, "Full enter your full name")<br/>
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
                <span class="label">Email Address *</span><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { @class = "txtContact" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Email, "Please ensure that a valid email is entered.")<br/>
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
            <span class="label">Telephone *</span><br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Telephone, new { @class = "txtContact" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Telephone, "Please enter a valid telephone number")<br/>
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
            <span class="label">Property Address (optional)</span><br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Address, new {@class = "txtContact" })<br />
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
            <span class="label">Subject *</span><br />
            @if (ViewBag.Pid != null) {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Subject, new {@class = "txtContact" })
            } else {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Subject, new { @class = "txtContact" })
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Subject, "Please enter a subject")<br/>
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
            <span class="label">Message *</span><br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.Message, new { @class = "txtContact" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Message, "Please enter a message")<br/>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="contact-btn" value="Send" />
        }
```

I simply need to know the best way for me to add the 'pid' and 'type' variables passed to the Contact Action from the Action link in the Sales Controller as values for my text boxes in the contact form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always extend your Model to include a PID and Type property.
In your form you could just enter `@Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.Pid)` and `@Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.Type)` (or `@Html.DisplayFor` if you want them visible)

If you didn't want to do that, you could put your PID and Type values into ViewBag or ViewData from the Action, and then put these values into form fields in your view.

**Edit:**
If you would like the Pid and Type to be part of your strongly typed view, you can change your model to be like the following:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    //all your other properties...
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string Pid { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Contact action, you can:

```
var model = new ContactModel() { ContactType = type, Pid = pid };
return View(model);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried the second suggestion of using the ViewBag and then adding @value = ViewBag.Pid to the input however, I found someone saying on another question on stack that it isn't possible to change strongly typed form field values, so I think that's a no go.

Regarding the first suggestion, how would I declare the values of these hidden fields to be the values in the url?